# Selenium WebDriver + Python - скриншоты

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Задача:
WebDriver перенаправляет на определенный url и потом ресайзит окно браузера - не менее 4х параметоров (ширина * высота). После каждого ресайза - делает скриншот.
Как на Python сделать так, чтобы файлу не задавать имя, а чтоб присваивалось каждый раз новое имя (к примеру дата и время скриншота) ну и сохранялось в image-формате.

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать так

```
name = str(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S'))
driver.save_screenshot(name+".png")
```